# Visual Studio 2017 - Using integrated console

Tags: python, windows, console, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with Python using the Windows version of Visual Studio 2017. Every time I run my code the external console pops up with the output. I'm looking for the option to switch to the integrated console. I can't find a way, but I find it hard to believe it can't be done. I don't see an option for this. Thanks.